# Equilence of Standard hamiltonian in an EM Field and coupling hamiltonian to magnetic Field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

If you look at a particle with charge -e in an electromagnetic field, its classical hamiltonian is given by:

$$
H(\vec{x}, \vec{p}) = \frac{1}{2m} ( \vec{p} + \frac{e}{c} \vec{A} (\vec{x}))^2 - e\Phi(\vec{x}) \\
=  \frac{1}{2m}\vec{p}^2 +  \frac{e}{2mc}( \vec{p}\vec{A}(\vec{x}) + \vec{A}(\vec{x})\vec{p} ) +  \frac{e^2}{2mc^2}  \vec{A}^2(\vec{x}) - e \Phi(\vec{x})
$$

However, when it comes for example to an electron in a magnetic field and you calculate, for example, the zeeman-effect, the hamiltonian is often given as

$$
H(\vec{x}, \vec{p}) = \frac{1}{2m}\vec{p}^2  - e \Phi(\vec{x}) - \frac{e}{2mc}\vec{L}\vec{B} = \\ \frac{1}{2m}\vec{p}^2  - e \Phi(\vec{x})-\frac{e}{2mc} (\vec{x} \times \vec{p}) (\nabla \times \vec{A}(\vec{x})
$$

Here of course, $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}$ are operators, but I thought I can also write down the "Classical" hamiltonian to formulate my question: Are those 2 Hamiltonians equivalent? Because I'm not able to show equivalence, and anytime I see the reasons for this interaction-hamiltonian, they are somewhat like "We know how a classical magnetic dipol interacts with an external field, so the hamiltonian must look like this", but they never are like "That's just what happens if you quantize the full classical EM-interaction-hamilton-function.

To say it mathematically: Does the equation:

$$
-\frac{e}{2mc} (\vec{x} \times \vec{p}) (\nabla \times \vec{A}(\vec{x})) = \frac{e}{2mc}( \vec{p}\vec{A}(\vec{x}) + \vec{A}(\vec{x})\vec{p} ) +  \frac{e^2}{2mc^2}  \vec{A}^2(\vec{x})
$$ 
hold? If not, does it hold if we assume x and p to be operators and use some commutation relations?

Edit: Despite my reasoning why it should be the same, I can't figure out how it can be the same. Problem 1: The left side contains derivations of $\vec{A}$, the righthandside doesn't. Similar, the righthandside contains a quadratic term in $\vec{A}$, while the lefthandside is linear.

Comment: This seems like a algebra question. Why don't you just do the calculation? If you can't get that to work, show us what you have done so far, and we can pin point the mistake.

Comment: It's more than an algebra question, because in principle I don't want to know how it's done, but instead if it can be done. And it would be more than an algebra question, because it constributes to the understanding of the hamiltonian of the electron. I'm sure that I'm not the first one to wonder where the hamiltonian of an electron in a magnetic field comes from. Yes, I need algebra to answer my question, but following this argument, many questions (every question whose answer contains a calculation) would be just algebra questions.

Comment: If you want to know if it can be done, just do the algebra and check whether it can be done. I mean, you have both Hamiltonians and you are asking if an algebraic manipulation may be done to bring one Hamiltonian into the form of the other. That is a question that requires only algebra to answer.

Comment: If I do it, and I fail, then I don't have the information wether it's due to my lack of abilities (that would mean I don't see the trick that you need to perform), or wether it's because I just can't do it. If you tell me "It can be done, trust me) then I sit down and do it. If you say "It can't be done" then why bother trying?  
Even if the question needed only algebra to answer (that is the "It can be done"-case), that still doesn't say something about how relevant or important this question is. There is a ton of other very important questions on this board, who also just need algebra.

Comment: If you do, and you fail, you post here all that you have tried (including details about the math) and we help you pinpoint what's going wrong (or right). But it is up to you to learn for yourself whether it can be done. Even if I tell you "It can't be done" you should not take my word for it. You *should* attempt it yourself.

Comment: Well, i did so before, and now I added the crucial points that prevent me from showing the equality.